# Split long regex in .clang-format file

Tags: regex, include, clang-format

I'm using clang format to sort and group include files. For some legacy reason I have to use long enough regex in `IncludeCategories` section. Style options described [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

```
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(very|long|regex|pattern|here)/'
    Priority:        2
```

Is there a (documented?) way to split such regex into multiple lines (without making a duplicate section with the same priority)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Did you try inserting new lines at desired places in a regex?**

I did just that and it is working in my case. Maybe there are some additional limitations and my example was simple enough so it worked. To test this issue I've copied a .clang-format from one of the open-source projects on Github and modified it slightly.

Initial .clang-format:

```
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^("boost/first.hpp")'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   true
  - Regex:           '^("boost/second.hpp")'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   true
  - Regex:           '^<(algorithm|any|array|atomic|barrier|bit|bitset|cassert|cctype|cerrno|cfenv|cfloat|charconv|chrono|cinttypes|climits|clocale|cmath|codecvt|compare|complex|concepts|condition_variable|coroutine|csetjmp|csignal|cstdarg|cstddef|cstdint|cstdio|cstdlib|cstring|ctime|cuchar|cwchar|cwctype|deque|exception|execution|filesystem|format|forward_list|fstream|functional|future|initializer_list|iomanip|ios|iosfwd|iostream|istream|iterator|latch|limits|list|locale|map|memory|memory_resource|mutex|new|numbers|numeric|optional|ostream|queue|random|ranges|ratio|regex|scoped_allocator|semaphore|set|shared_mutex|source_location|span|sstream|stack|stdexcept|stop_token|streambuf|string|string_view|strstream|syncstream|system_error|thread|tuple|typeindex|typeinfo|type_traits|unordered_map|unordered_set|utility|valarray|variant|vector|version)>'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   true
  - Regex:           '^<(assert|complex|ctype|errno|fenv|float|inttypes|iso646|limits|locale|math|setjmp|signal|stdalign|stdarg|stdatomic|stdbool|stddef|stdint|stdio|stdlib|stdnoreturn|string|tgmath|threads|time|uchar|wchar|wctype)\.h>'
    Priority:        4
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   true
```

Initial source code ordering:

```
#include "boost/first.hpp"
#include "boost/second.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <codecvt>
#include <cuchar>
#include <fstream>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <random>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
```

Modified .clang-format. Notice that the third regex now spans across multiple lines and its priority is changed from 3 to 1. Pipes are added at both the end and the beginning of each split regex line.

```
    IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^("boost/first.hpp")'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   true
  - Regex:           '^("boost/second.hpp")'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   true
  - Regex:           '^<(algorithm|any|array|atomic|barrier|bit|bitset|cassert|cctype|cerrno|cfenv|cfloat|charconv|chrono|cinttypes|climits|clocale|cmath|
                        |codecvt|compare|complex|concepts|condition_variable|coroutine|csetjmp|csignal|cstdarg|cstddef|cstdint|cstdio|cstdlib|cstring|ctime|
                        |cuchar|cwchar|cwctype|deque|exception|execution|filesystem|format|forward_list|fstream|functional|future|initializer_list|iomanip|ios|
                        |iosfwd|iostream|istream|iterator|latch|limits|list|locale|map|memory|memory_resource|mutex|new|numbers|numeric|optional|ostream|queue|
                        |random|ranges|ratio|regex|scoped_allocator|semaphore|set|shared_mutex|source_location|span|sstream|stack|stdexcept|stop_token|streambuf|
                        |string|string_view|strstream|syncstream|system_error|thread|tuple|typeindex|typeinfo|type_traits|unordered_map|unordered_set|utility|
                        |valarray|variant|vector|version)>'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   true
  - Regex:           '^<(assert|complex|ctype|errno|fenv|float|inttypes|iso646|limits|locale|math|setjmp|signal|stdalign|stdarg|stdatomic|stdbool|stddef|stdint|stdio|stdlib|stdnoreturn|string|tgmath|threads|time|uchar|wchar|wctype)\.h>'
    Priority:        4
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   true
```

Modified source code ordering. Notice how `boost/second.hpp` was included after all includes that now have greater priority. Headers that end the line (e.g. `cmath` and `streambuf`) as well as headers that start a new line (e.g. `codecvt` and `iosfwd`) are ordered correctly:

```
#include "boost/first.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <codecvt>
#include <cuchar>
#include <fstream>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <random>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>
#include "boost/second.hpp"
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
```

Comment: Did you try how the headers that start a new line sorted? These are `codecvt`, `cuchar`, `iosfwd`, `random`, `string` and `valarray` from your modified .clang-format file.

Comment: I've updated my example so that the `clang-format` formats headers that end the regex line, headers that start a new regex line, and some headers in between of those.

Comment: is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: Not that I know of.
I've made an educated guess that it might work with this approach, based on how the most parser work.

Comment: Could you please specify which version of clang-format you have used?

Comment: Output of `clang-format --version`: `Ubuntu clang-format version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1`

Comment: If this answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted and assign a bounty